# Show/hide elements with checkbox check/unchek

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show and hide `tr` of table with checkbox check and uncheck. I tried the following script not working for me.

```js
$('.checks').on('ifChecked', function(event) {
  var checked = $(this).val();
  if (checked == 1) {
    $('.vegetables').show();
  }
  if (checked == 2) {
    $('.fruits').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="1">vegetables
   </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="2">Fruits
   </label>
</div>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="vegetables hidden">
      <td colspan="2">
        <h2>Vegetablese:</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vegetables hidden">
      <td>
        <label>Vegetables:</label>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fruits hidden">
      <td colspan="2">
        <h2>Fruits:</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fruits hidden">
      <td>
        <label>Fuits:</label>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What event is `ifChecked` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

- Change `ifChecked` with `onchange`. There's no event like `ifChecked`.
- Use `toggle` based on the state of the checkbox.
- Check for `$(this).checked` to find the state. This will return true or false.

```js
$('.checks').on('change', function(event) {
  var checked = $(this).val();
  if (checked == 1) {
    $('.vegetables').toggle($(this).checked);
  }
  if (checked == 2) {
    $('.fruits').toggle($(this).checked);
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="1" /> vegetables
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="2" /> Fruits
  </label>
</div>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="vegetables hidden">
      <td colspan="2">
        <h2>Vegetablese:</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vegetables hidden">
      <td>
        <label>Vegetables:</label>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fruits hidden">
      <td colspan="2">
        <h2>Fruits:</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fruits hidden">
      <td>
        <label>Fuits:</label>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Eniol Anything else you need? 

Comment: I am still checking it at my end.

Comment: @Eniol Thanks! 

Answer (score 0):

Theres a couple of issues in your logic. Firstly `ifChecked` is not a valid event. Use `change` instead. Secondly the logic doesn't work to hide elements. To do that you'd need to loop through all checkboxes and determine their state in order to show/hide the content underneath.

The simplest and most extensible way to achieve what you require is to use a `data` attribute to specify which element should be toggled when the checkbox is updated. Then you can simply hide/show each element in the set. Try this:

```js
let $checks = $('.checks').on('change', () => $checks.each((i, el) => $(el.dataset.target).toggle(el.checked)));
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="1" data-target=".vegetables">vegetables
   </label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
   <input type="checkbox" class="checks" value="2" data-target=".fruits">Fruits
   </label>
</div>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="vegetables hidden">
      <td colspan="2">
        <h2>Vegetablese:</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="vegetables hidden">
      <td>
        <label>Vegetables:</label>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fruits hidden">
      <td colspan="2">
        <h2>Fruits:</h2>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fruits hidden">
      <td>
        <label>Fuits:</label>
        <input type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```